# How do I make my windows partition show up at boot time without holding option?

Tags: macos, windows, partition

How do I make my windows partition show up at boot time without holding option?

I had this setup on a Macbook pro way back when that was setup this way. I recently bought an iMac and would like to decide which partition I want to use at runtime without holding option. Is this still an available feature? Right now it automatically loads the windows partition.

Comment: Don't know if this is something that you could benefit from, but I thought I'd mention [Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com/eu/products/desktop/), which allows you to install windows on top of Mac as an application, essentially. [It also has a hybrid mode, which allows you to run Windows apps on Mac](http://www.parallels.com/eu/products/desktop/#c98181). If you're looking to do something that on it's own will be very process heavy (_for example gaming_), then you can probably forget about this.

Comment: I would rather hold option then run virtual box and rather run virtual box then run parallels. Thanks though!

Comment: Why would you run Virtual box with Parallels desktop though?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no default boot loader option built-in to Macs. Your best bet is going with a custom bootloader like rEFInd (see http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ for download and instructions). Normally I don't just include a link and call it a day but obviously I'm not going to have an alternative download available for someone else's program... and if the program is still available to download, the instructions will be right there with it at the program's site.

If after downloading, reading the documentation, and attempting the setup for this you still have issues, I recommend putting up a fresh question specific to that.

Aside from that, there are no options without getting very low level into nvram settings that you do NOT want to mess with... or at the very least I will not help someone mess with.

Good luck!